# SignalR HubConnection closing instantly without error

Tags: c#, .net, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am trying to make a single application that is both a Client and Server using SignalR in .NET. The end goal is to integrate it with our existing product, which requires to be both a client and server as one computer acts as both, while the other computers are all clients.

[Full source code on GitHub.](https://github.com/CarsonRoscoe/SignalRMessaging/)

In the Client startup code, which is run after the Server startup code has completed, the following code is run:

```
m_hubConnection = new HubConnection( "http://localhost:8080/" );
m_myHubProxy = m_hubConnection.CreateHubProxy( nameof( ServerHub ) );
m_myHubProxy.On<string, string>( nameof( ServerHub.BroadCastMessage ), ( name, message ) => OnMessageReceived( name, message ) );
m_hubConnection.Closed += OnClosed;
m_hubConnection.Error += OnErrorReceived;
await m_hubConnection.Start(new WebSocketTransport()); 
await SendMessage( "Startup", "Sending from same thread as connection established" );
```

The OnClosed callback is called almost right away, so the connection closes immediately upon starting.

The OnErrorReceived callback is never called, so it does not close due to any obvious error

The Start method hangs and never calls back

The SendMessage method is never hit

---

Ideally, I want the connection to open, stay open, have that SendMessage be hit, send a message to the Hub, and have that broadcast the same message back to the client.

Any ideas on what's going wrong?

Comment: What if you change the URL to `http://localhost:8080/signalr`?

Comment: Gave it a try and did not work. The StartUp configuration is mapping with a "/signalr" path. Also tried adding "/signalr" to the server's string (and both together), but no combination worked

Comment: In your browsers network tab, you should see `connect?transport=.....` and `start?transport=.....`.  Are those getting 200 responses?  In the case of the second request, what does the response body contain?  Does your server have websockets enabled?  (If you aren't using a browser to test this, you can still use Fiddler to intercept and inspect the requests/responses)

Comment: Should have clarified, I'm not doing it through ASP.NET web pages, it's a console application. I forked this project to try this off of a repo with two console applications, so I'm trying to merge two working console applications into one. So no info in the browser's Network tab. If you want to compare or see,


[Here's the original 2 console programs working](https://github.com/screig/SignalRMessaging) and 

[here's my merged not working version](https://github.com/CarsonRoscoe/SignalRMessaging/)

Comment: You can still gather diagnostics using fiddler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, insanely silly mistake. I just switched from port 8080 to 8089. I guess something else is using port 8080, but regardless, switching both the client and server side to port 8089 fixed it.